# Passing arguments to an iframe

Tags: php, iframe, widget

I am building an IFrame for the first time and trying to make a widget.

What I am trying to do is let people pass a hike id and then display on a google map everything that happened on that hike.  Right now I am just starting to get into how to make this a widget.

I need to pass the hike id variable into the widget, but I am not sure how, or whether things are done this way.

What I have now is one page called widget.php with this code:

```
<blink>
        <iframe src="hike_widget.php" width="100%" height="300">
    </iframe>
</blink>
```

And that is accessed by this URL:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/widget.php?type=hike&hike_id=108

And then called the hike_widget.php file which displays text.  Is this the general way to do this?  How do I pass the hike id from widget.php to hike_widget.php ?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd pass the hike_id like this:

```
<iframe src="hike_widget.php?hike_id=108" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why are you so against IFrames?  I think many widgets are done with IFrames...no? :)

Comment: By "widget", do you mean that you want to allow people on other websites (other domains) to insert an iframe tag to load your map? That's an appropriate use of an iframe. However, scripts running inside the iframe will be running in a different domain, so browser security restrictions will prevent communication between scripts inside and outside the frame. Consider this carefully. It may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it with the `form` also. Here's a simple example with `post` method:

```
<form action="hike_widget.php" target="hike_widget" method="post">

  <input type="number" name="hike_id">

  <button type="submit">Pass arguments</button>

</form>

<iframe name="hike_widget" src="hike_widget.php"></iframe>
```

P.s. You can also use `get` method.